# Lucene special character search

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am trying to move from Database search to Lucene search. I have few textfiles which has data, sample data in one of the text file is

> N=Ethernet, L=null, IM=XX123, SN=286-054-754, HBF=null, BON=null,
>   VSR=null, DUID=null, MID=2, IP=10.21.122.136, MAC=60:C7:98:17:57:80,
>   SYNC=false, GN=null, CustParam3=null, CustParam2=null, VV=1.06.0007,
>   CustParam5=null, CustParam4=null, CustParam7=null, CustParam6=null,
>   BUNAME=null, PN=M132-409-01-R, CustParam8=null, CS=2015-09-30
>   19:49:25.0, CST=Inactive, BL=3.2, EE=Off, TID=190, PRL=VEM, PAV=null,
>   FAV=null, MON=2016-04-06 11:13:40.507, DON=null, LPDR=2015-09-30
>   19:50:23.85, SSID=null, PIP=null, DID=null, MDATE=null,
>   OV=rel-20120625-SC-3.1.2-B, CID=null, ICBI=false, TID=null,
>   LCR=2015-10-01 01:50:30.297, SS=No-Recent-Communication, CBU=null,
>   GMVR=, LID=store, FF=167340, HFP=RATNERCO >> blore, ISA=false,
>   TF=null, FAM=null, LDPDR=2015-09-30 19:50:39.113, STVER=True,
>   SID=null, LHB=2015-09-30 21:50:30.297, IDSS=false, FR=81796,
>   LMOS=2015-09-30 19:49:50.503, LCUS=null, MNAME=XX 123, BBUID=null,
>   CON=null, DBUN=null, ISDRA=false, POSV=null, UUID=2, TRAM=null,
>   SPOL=000000000, CustomField1=null, CustomField2=null,
>   CustomField3=null, MUID=2DE02CF3-0663-420A-8918-7A550E29F570,
>   CustomField4=null, CustomField5=null, HNAME=blore, customparam1=null,
>   HID=1048, LBDT=2015-07-06 12:03:45.0, DIC=null, AT=None, LID=null,
>   IDSA=false, LMPS=2015-09-30 15:49:50.457, MBUN=System, CNC=Ethernet,
>   LOC=null

I am creating index and searching using StandardAnalyzer, but I am unable to search with the string UUID=1, the value which I am getting here is 
also that which does **NOT** have UUID=1 (In total I have two Files and both the files content are getting displayed). As the data has special characters I also tried using WhiteSpaceAnalyzer, but then it did not return any data. I created a custom analyzer which has whitespace, lowercase and standard token filter, but it did not help. I also extended StopwordAnalyzerBase to create my own analyzer and used NormalizeCharMap for replacing the special characters, it helped but I was not able to do wildcard search.

Request someone to help me out in this. I am very new to Lucene.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongPoint;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class IndexCreator
{
public void createIndex(String inputFiles,  String indexPath)
{
    //Input Path Variable
    final Path docDir = Paths.get(inputFiles);

    try
    {
        //org.apache.lucene.store.Directory instance
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open( Paths.get(indexPath) );

        //analyzer with the default stop words
        //Analyzer analyzer = new NewStandardAnalyzer();
        //Analyzer analyzer =  buildAnalyzer();
        //Analyzer analyzer =  new WhitespaceAnalyzer();

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        //IndexWriter Configuration
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

        //IndexWriter writes new index files to the directory
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

        //Its recursive method to iterate all files and directories
        indexDocs(writer, docDir);

        writer.commit();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void indexDocs(final IndexWriter writer, Path path) throws 
IOException
{
    //Directory?
    if (Files.isDirectory(path))
    {
        //Iterate directory
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
        {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
            {
                try
                {
                    //Index this file
                    indexDoc(writer, file, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //Index this file
        indexDoc(writer, path, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
    }
}

private void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, long lastModified) throws IOException
{
    try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file))
    {
        //Create lucene Document
        Document doc = new Document();

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file));
        //content = content.replace("-", "\\-");
        //content = content.replace(":", "\\:");
        //content = content.replace("=", "\\=");
        //content = content.replace(".", "\\.");
        doc.add(new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new LongPoint("modified", lastModified));
        doc.add(new TextField("contents", content, Store.YES));

        //Updates a document by first deleting the document(s)
        //containing <code>term</code> and then adding the new
        //document.  The delete and then add are atomic as seen
        //by a reader on the same index
        writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
    }
}

    public static Analyzer buildAnalyzer() throws IOException {
        return CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer("whitespace")
                .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
                .addTokenFilter("standard")
                .build();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        IndexCreator indexCreator = new IndexCreator();indexCreator.createIndex(
"C:\\Lucene\\LuceneLatest\\LuceneLatestModified\\Data", 
 , 
"C:\\Lucene\\LuceneLatest\\LuceneLatestModified\\Index");
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class Searcher
{
//directory contains the lucene indexes
private static final String INDEX_DIR = 
"C:\\Lucene\\LuceneLatest\\LuceneLatestModified\\Index";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //Create lucene searcher. It search over a single IndexReader.
    Searcher searcher = new Searcher(); 

    //Search indexed contents using search term
    /*searcher.searchInContent("NETWORKCONFIGURATION=Ethernet AND MACADDRESS=60\\:C7\\:98\\:17\\:57\\:80", searcher.createSearcher());
    searcher.searchInContent("NETWORKCONFIGURATION=Ethern*", searcher.createSearcher());*/
    searcher.searchInContent("UUID=1", searcher.createSearcher());

}

private void searchInContent(String textToFind, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
{
    //Create search query
    //QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("contents", new StandardAnalyzer());

    QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("contents", new StandardAnalyzer());
    //textToFind = QueryParser.escape(textToFind).toLowerCase();
    Query query = qp.parse(textToFind);


    //search the index
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10);

    System.out.println("Total Results :: " + hits.totalHits);

    for (ScoreDoc sd : hits.scoreDocs)
    {
        Document d = searcher.doc(sd.doc);
        System.out.println("Path : "+ d.get("path") + ", Score : " + sd.score + ", Content : "+d.get("contents"));
    }

}

private IndexSearcher createSearcher() throws IOException
{
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));

    //It is an interface for accessing a point-in-time view of a lucene index
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);

    //Index searcher
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    return searcher;
}

public static Analyzer buildAnalyzer() throws IOException {
    return CustomAnalyzer.builder()
            .withTokenizer("whitespace")
            .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
            .addTokenFilter("standard")
            .build();}}
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, sorry to ask, but, where in this code is the query part? Your quetion is about the query itself, isn't it?

Comment: Hi @nicolasl 
searcher.searchInContent("UUID=1", searcher.createSearcher());  UUID=1 is the text which I want to search.

Comment: I want to search a particular content in the txt file, the content is dynamic and the txt file can contain special characters. Also I should be able to do a wildcard search.

Comment: Now it's there :) well, I'm not a Lucene expert, but, I've played with Solr a while ago. I think what you need is a phrase search, that will look for the exact match of your search query. Try using PhraseQuery class instead of Quey class and post here the outcome. Here's some doc for you to dig out: -https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html and http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I used PhraseQuery in the below way,
//Create search query
        //QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("contents", new StandardAnalyzer());
        
        /*QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("contents", new StandardAnalyzer());
        //textToFind = QueryParser.escape(textToFind).toLowerCase();
        Query query = qp.parse(textToFind);*/
        
        PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery("contents",textToFind);
        
        //search the index
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10);

No documents were found, should I change Analyzer?